# What is the difference between an RNAV and a GPS approach?

Tags: instrument-procedures

How does the FAA decide to name an approach an "RNAV" approach or a "GPS" approach?

Is it because for RNAV approaches, there is the option to use something besides GPS like an inertial navigation system based on ground NAVAIDs vs GPS which actually requires use of the US maintained and monitored GNSS GPS system?

Comment: Are there specific approaches you have in mind?  As of right now, all new GPS approaches should be named RNAV (GPS) ...

Comment: I think the convention going forward is to unify the name to "RNP Approach"